# PHP - how to remove data using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove `?cat=` from the example 1 so it can look like example 2 using PHP.

Example 1

```
?cat=some-cat
```

Example 2

```
some-cat
```

Comment: Remove how and from what? Please add some more info about this (maybe some real world examples as well), there are parsing functions for this

Comment: @Pekka, I think the question says it all remove `?cat=` ?cat=some-cat, ?cat=some-cat2, ?cat=some-cat3 and so on.

Comment: @common no, not necessarily. You are showing a query string. Can it contain more parameters than `?cat=`? If no, a simple `str_replace()` will be sufficient. If yes, you will need to properly parse the string

Comment: @common What exactly is the context for this? Where is `?cat=some-cat` coming from?

Comment: @Pekka can you give an example if there is more parameters?

Comment: @common `?cat=some-cat&page=5`

Comment: @lonesomeday a database.

Comment: @common yes, but *what kind of data is it*? Why does it look like a query string?

Comment: @common: If that is just the page querystring you just need to look at `$_GET`... you should probably clarify the question

Comment: @Pekka because it will be part of a query string.

Comment: I give up - you're not giving enough information to answer this in depth. If `str_replace()` works for you, the problem is solved; otherwise, you will need to explain what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$cat = '?cat=some-cat';
$cat = str_replace('?cat=', '', $cat);
```

**EDIT**:

If you are pulling this query string through something like `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, then I'd opt for you to use `$_GET`, which is an associative array of the GET variables passed to your script, so if your query string looked like this:

```
?cat=some-cat&dog=some-dog
```

The `$_GET` array would look like this:

```
(
   'cat' => 'some-cat',
   'dog' => 'some-dog'
)


$cat = $_GET['cat']; //some-cat
$dog = $_GET['dog']; //some-dog
```

**Another edit**:

Say you had an associative array of query vars you wish to append onto a URL string, you'd do something like this:

```
$query_vars = array();
$query_vars['cat'] = 'some-cat';
$query_vars['dog'] = 'some-dog';

foreach($query_vars as $key => $value) {
   $query_vars[] = $key . '=' . $value;
   unset($query_vars[$key]);
}

$query_string = '?' . implode('&', $query_vars); //?cat=some-cat&dog=some-dog
```

Comment: what if I dont now how many variables are going top be passed?

Comment: @common You can build up an associative array and then iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, very easily:

```
$cat = '?cat=some-cat';
$cat = substr($cat, 5); // remove the first 5 characters of $cat
```

This may not be the best way to do this. That will depend on what you are attempting to achieve...